# Display Dashcode Browser in App with SIngle NavBar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller, dashcode

How can I display a Dashcode created Browser template in a UIWebView, that the user can dismiss, without having two navigation bars? In the photo below, you'll see that the top bar is part of an Xcode navigation controller with a back button for the purpose of letting the user leave the web view. The lower bar is for the Dashcode created stack and pop of the content hierarchy that the user navigates.

As far as I know, you can't put a button in a web page, Dashcode or otherwise, that will dismiss a cocoa app view controller. If I hide the Xcode navbar, the user can't get rid of the web view when they're done. I can't hide the Dashcode navbar or the user can't navigate the content.

As some background, what I'm trying to accomplish is in-app documentation that I host on the web. Similar to how the Apple iPhone Cards app does with its Help view. This would allow me to update the documentation via my web page, without needing to update the app itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be floating a Done button in a transparent view that floats over the top of the web view. Thereby giving the effect that the Done button (from Xcode IB) is part of the NavBar from Dashcode Browser template.